# Value and reference types

Tags: javascript

I know that there are 6 data types in JavaScript.

What are the "reference" types in JavaScript and what are the "value" data types in JavaScript?. Could someone list them by these 2 categories?

Comment: Where did you hear of these categories existing?

Comment: from strongly typed languages.. like C#, Java..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`undefined`, `null`, `number`, `string`, `boolean` and `object` of which only `object` is a "reference" type.

There is no assignment by reference or pass by reference in javascript, whenever you pass/assign a "reference" type, you pass/assign a copy of the reference, you don't create a reference of the reference which would have different implications.

You can use these functions:

```
function isReferenceType( value ) {
     return Object(value) === value;
}

function isPrimitiveType( value ) {
     return Object(value) !== value;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [standard#sec-8](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)

> The ECMAScript language types are Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, Number, and Object

The only `"reference"` type is the `Object`.

Answer (score 3):

undefined, null, number, string, boolean and object

object is a reference type.